# How to change button images from another class?

Tags: swift, button, sprite-kit, imagebutton

I´m new to coding and I want to know how to change the buton image in the menu class from the setting class.

Here is the menu class:

```
class Mainmenu: SKScene{

 var ratingButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "RatingButton1")
}
```

In my setting class I want to change this image to "RatingButton2" just by clicking a button.

Here is the setting class:

```
class Settings: SKScene {

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

 self.backgroundColor = SKColor.white

 let DCButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ChangeButton")
 DCButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width * 0.2, y: self.size.height * 0.8)
 DCButton.setScale(0.53)
 self.addChild(DCButton)
 }

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches{

        let locationUser = touch.location(in: self)

        if atPoint(locationUser) == DCButton {

        //Change the button image here

        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: What happened to the docs? (I think your code might be easier on my eye with less waste of vertical space.)

Comment: @greybeard done

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3+** Use Notificationcenter to update your button image.

// Define identifier

```
let notificationName = Notification.Name("NotificationIdentifier")

// Register to receive notification in Mainmenu
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(receivedNotification), name: notificationName, object: nil)


// Post notification into Settings write this line into "touchesBegan" method
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notificationName, object: nil)


// Stop listening notification if required.
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: notificationName, object: nil)
```

**Notification Handler**

```
func receivedNotification(notification: Notification){
   // Set your button image here...
}
```

Comment: I don´t know what exactly to put in the  func @Shiv Kumar

Comment: Write this line into your Menucontroller viewdidload.

// Register to receive notification in Mainmenu
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(receivedNotification), name: notificationName, object: nil)

func receivedNotification(notification: Notification){
   // Set your button image here...
}

Comment: write this line into your "touchesBegan"
// Post notification into Settings write this line into "touchesBegan" method
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notificationName, object: nil)

Comment: In the menu class, I get this error twice:  Use of unresolved identifier 'receivedNotification' @Shiv Kumar

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using NSNotificationCenter for this task, it adds a lot of overhead for something that will be rarely used.

Now unfortunately I do not know how your layout is structured, so I am not sure what answer is best for you.

If Menu and Settings are both on the scene at the same time,  then you can search the scene to find the button you are looking for:

```
class Mainmenu: SKScene{

    var ratingButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "RatingButton1")
    ratingButton.name = "ratingButton"

}

class Settings: SKScene {

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        self.backgroundColor = SKColor.white

        let DCButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ChangeButton")
        DCButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width * 0.2, y: self.size.height * 0.8)
        DCButton.setScale(0.53)
        self.addChild(DCButton)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches{
            let locationUser = touch.location(in: self)
            if atPoint(locationUser) == DCButton {
                let button = scene.childNode(withName:"//ratingButton") as! SKSpriteNode
                button.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed:"RatingButton2")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If it is not on the scene and you are presenting it, then you want to use `userData` to assign what your button is before hand

```
let menu = Mainmenu(...)
menu.userData = ["ratingButton":SKTexture(imageNamed:textureName)] //texture name is either Ratingbutton1 or RatingButton2 depending on state
self.view.presentScene(menu)
```

Then in the `viewDidLoad`,  just read the `userData`

```
func viewDidLoad(...)
{
    ratingButton.texture = userData?["ratingButton"]

}
```

Comment: In which Scenes do I have to put these two parts of the code? @KnightofDragon